# About Kotlin with Data binding For View model

Tags: kotlin

I get a run time error while use data binding with view model in Kotlin.

My xml code is like this:

```
<data >
    <variable name="wordData"
        type="com.example.android.roomwordssample.Word"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@style/word_title"
    android:text="@{word.word}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
```

And my adapter's code is like this:

```
inner class WordViewHolder(val binding: RecyclerviewItemBinding):
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

While run got this error:

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure put same name as you taken in data Like this

```
<data >
    <variable name="wordData"
        type="com.example.android.roomwordssample.Word"/>
</data>
```

Now Replace variable name word to wordData and your error is solved.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@style/word_title"
    android:text="@{word.word}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
```